# d3js rescale redraw barchart without new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple (o.k. not so simple) barchart which shows the electric power consumption of one consumer (C1). I add the consumption of another consumer (C2) as line. The max consumption of C2 if higher then the max consumption of C1 so I have to rescale. I have solved this problem but not as beautiful I wanted to.

I calculate the new yMax, set the domain, rescale the axis (beautiful) remove all 'rect' and redraw (not beautiful). Is there a possibility to say: hey bars, I have a new scale, go down with a beautiful animation :)

Here the rescale method:

```
var rescale = function () {
            //in this function the new _maxYValue is set
            renderLineView();
            var data = _data;
            y.domain([_minYValue, _maxYValue]);
            _svg.select(".y.axis")
                        .transition().duration(1500).ease("sin-in-out")
                        .call(yAxis());
            _svg.selectAll("rect").remove();

            var barWidth = getBarWidth(data.length);

            var bars = d3.select("#layer_1").selectAll(".bar").data(data, function (d) {
                return d.xValue;
            });

            bars.enter().append("rect")
                         .attr("class", "daybarincomplete")
                         .attr("x", function (d, i) {

                             return x(d.xValue) + 4;
                         })
                         .attr("width", barWidth)
                         .attr("y", function (d) {
                             return Math.min(y(0), y(d.value));
                         })
                         .attr("height", function (d) {
                             return Math.abs(y(d.value) - y(0));
                         });

        }
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/axman/v4qc7/5/

thx in advance

©a-x-i

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.transition()` call on bars, to determine the behaviour you want when the data changes (e.g. Bar heights change). You'd chain the `.attr()` function after it to set bar height etc.

To deal with data points that disappear between refreshes (e.g. You had 10 bars originally but now only have 9), chain the `.exit().remove()` functions to bars.

With both of the above, you can additionally chain something like  `.duration(200).ease('linear')` to make it look all pretty.

Comment: wuuuh, thank you. You didn't give me the answer but you lead me to the solution :)

http://jsfiddle.net/axman/v4qc7/7/

Answer (score 0):

pretty much what @ninjaPixel said. There's a easy to follow example here
http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_09/05_transition.html